# Secondary screen freezes after sleep on Win10

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors

I have a PC with Win-10 and dedicated NVIDIA video card. I have two monitors in extended mode. All works fine, until I send PC sleep.

When I **wake up** my PC, the **secondary display** (which doesn't shows the Start menu) **freezes the frame**. **Only the mouse pointer can move on that display.** No windows can be moved on that monitor, and no other interaction can be done (writing, clicking etc.) (The main monitor and Windows is still live.) The broken screen cannot be identified (the big "1" or "2" doesn't appeares) by clicking to identify monitors (in display settings)

**I have done:**

1. I have updated NVDIA driver (doesn't solve)
2. I have swap displays to make the the broken as the main display. In this case the main worked well (phyisically the other display), but the new secondary still freezes.
3. Restarting the graphics drivers by `Win+Ctrl+Shift+B` (doesn't solve)
4. Windows restart solves (daily restart not accepted)

**How to resolve this display freeze?**

**System:**

- OS: Win 10 Pro
- Build: 10.0.17763
- NVidia driver version: 26.21.14.3039  (17/04/2019)

[image]

Comment: Running into this very issue now - were you able to resolve it?

Comment: I also have this problem. I found another thread about it: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/dual-screen-setup-second-screen-freezing-up/4a74ae2d-8c2e-400e-bdee-0a5b208b03df

Answer (score 4):

I'm posting this for posterity, because it took me forever to find a quick fix (not permanent) to this problem and I found it on a random forum post, but this is what I do (YMMV).

Open task manager and find "Desktop Windows Manager" or dwm.exe and end it. It gives a warning that the computer can become unstable and shut down, and it has you check a box and click "Shut Down" but it always goes back to normal for me afterwards. The screen flashes a bit but then I regain control of the second monitor.

Again, this is a temporary fix until Windows acknowledges the problem and starts actually providing solutions instead of "restart your computer" but it's easier than unplugging an HDMI cord every time you put the computer to sleep.

Answer (score 1):

> Previously I answered it, but it got deleted as moderator didn't realise I was offering my context and what fixed it for me. I'll make it clearer what has been working for the last few months now:

Exact same issue I had it seems, as intermittent as it was, was a pain. I tried updating drivers. Swapping main screen setting. The second always froze when in extend display mode, only showing mouse movement and the background. Then needed to shutdown once problem occurred to fix.  No issue if duplicating.

To  the mix was one monitor at home and another in the office.

> For me this worked, before moving location:
>
> - Prior to shutdown/restart/hibernate: unplug HDMI cord.
> - Once booting back in Windows: re-plug HDMI cord.

Not perfect, but much more preferable. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same issue when waking from hibernate. As sudgested at [answers.microsoft.com](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/second-monitor-is-frozen-when-waking-from-sleep/18bffb80-48b8-4fcd-96ec-04921c65af46?page=1) leaving hdmi cable plugged in, hibernating and then waking up from hibernate for the second time unfreezes the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it'll be useful to anyone:

My unit is old Fujitsu P710, fairly standard business aimed, core i3 based pc.
BIOS: Aptio Setup Utility | Code ver. 4.6.5.3

I fixed the issue with secondary monitor not waking up after exiting sleep mode
by changing bios settings:

Go to Power tab:
 change "Hibernate like Soft OFF" value to disabled.

Save & exit.

That's it. Problem went away in my case.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise tailor your answer to this question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.